# Height/ Width of a cropped circle given the radius and angles subtended at center

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have the following image:

[image]

I need to get the width and height of the arch. Lets say the radius is `200px` and the arch angle is `50°` for one side and `-160°` for the other. How would I get the height and width.

[image]

In this second example, I just want the height and width of the red part. It has an angle of `-30°` and `-60°`, or a total of `30°` and the radius is still `200px`.

Ideally, I would like to be able to get both of those answers with the same equation and if at all possible, could you explain it in a way where I would be able to convert it to python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of terms of distance. You need to find the size of the smallest rectangle that could contain your cropped disk.

[image]

You take two angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. I assume that:

$$180° \geq \theta_1 \geq \theta_2 \geq -180°$$

Let's compute $h = y_{\mathrm{max}}-y_{\mathrm{min}}$ and $w=x_{\mathrm{max}}-x_{\mathrm{min}}$,so you have different possibilities:

$\bullet $ if $\theta_1\geq 0 \geq \theta_2$  then $x_{\mathrm{max}} = r$ and $x_{\mathrm{min}} = \mathrm{min}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\})$

$\bullet $ if $0>\theta_1 \geq \theta_2$  then $x_{\mathrm{max}} = \mathrm{max}(r \cos \theta_1, 0)$ and $x_{\mathrm{min}} = \mathrm{min}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\})$

$\bullet $ if $\theta_1 \geq \theta_2>0$  then $x_{\mathrm{max}} = \mathrm{max}(r \cos \theta_2, 0)$ and $x_{\mathrm{min}} = \mathrm{min}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\})$

We can sum this up in:

$x_{\mathrm{min}} = \mathrm{min}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\}) $

If $\theta_1  \theta_2 \geq 0$ then $x_{\mathrm{max}} = \mathrm{max}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\})$ else $x_{\mathrm{max}} = r$

Therefore:

$$ \boxed{w= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
   \mathrm{max}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\})-\mathrm{min}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\}) \; \mathrm{if} \; \theta_1 \theta_2 \geq 0 \\
   r-\mathrm{min}(\{0,r \cos \theta_1,r \cos \theta_2\}) \text{ otherwise} \\
\end{array} \right.}$$

Let's do the same for $h$:

$\bullet$ if $180°\geq\theta_1 \geq 90°$ :
$\quad $ if $\theta_2 \geq 90°$ then $y_{\mathrm{max}} = r \sin \theta_2$ else $y_{\mathrm{max}} = r$

$\bullet$ if $90°>\theta_1$ then $y_{\mathrm{max}} = \mathrm{max}(\{0,r \sin \theta_1\}) $

$\bullet$ if $-180°\leq\theta_2 \leq -90°$ :
$\quad $ if $\theta_1 \leq -90°$ then $y_{\mathrm{min}} = r \sin \theta_1$ else $y_{\mathrm{min}} = -r$

$\bullet$ if $-90°<\theta_2 $ then $y_{\mathrm{min}} = \mathrm{min}(\{0,r \sin \theta_2\}) $

$$ \boxed{h= y_{\mathrm{max}}-y_{\mathrm{min}}} $$

So in python you can write the following function with `r` your radius, `theta_1`,`theta_2` the angles. For example `theta1 = 160`,`theta2 = -50`  in your first example and `theta1 = 60`,`theta2 = 30` in your second example.

```
from math import *

def width_and_height(r,theta1,theta2):
    L_x = [0,r*cos(radians(theta1)),r*cos(radians(theta2))]
    L_y = [0,r*sin(radians(theta1)),r*sin(radians(theta2))]
    
    if theta1*theta2 >= 0:
        w = max(L_x)-min(L_x)
    else:
        w = r-min(L_x)
    
    if 180>=theta1>=90:
        if theta2>=90:
            y_max = L_y[2]
        else:
            y_max = r
    else:
        y_max = max(L_y)
    
    if -180<=theta2<=-90:
        if theta1<=-90:
            y_min = L_y[1]
        else:
            y_min = -r
    else:
        y_min = min(L_y)
    
    h = y_max-y_min
    
    return w,h
```

Comment: In inkscape (where I created the images above) it says the height and width of the first image should be `h=353.209`, `w=393.654`. But when I test your function, I'm getting back `(200.0, 4.898587196589413e-14)`.

Here is a link that shows the issue: http://tpcg.io/y7sISwLk

Comment: So that seems to only get me the width and height from `A1` to `A3`. In this case, the width would need to be `A2` to `A3` and the height needs to be the top of the circle to `A1`. >>> http://tpcg.io/pamI7Ll0

Comment: @ToMakPo I have fully edited my answer. It should be good now. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I feel like I now have a much better understanding of this too.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I do not offend you if I consider in this small answer that you are not at ease with "signed trigonometry" i.e., with signed sine, cosine or tangent.

If such is the case, the trick is to do all computations always in the first quadrant (in which $\cos, \sin, \tan$ are all positive); you can do it by for example for the first figure, by **folding** the left hand side piece along the vertical axis, in order to transform angle $160°$ into an angle $20°$ giving for example $w=200+200\cos(20°))$, (think to $\cos 20°$ as a "shrinking factor") etc.

If you have a more heavy use of trigonometry, you will have to switch to this definition of cosine and sine : $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ are the coordinates of the point $M$ having a polar angle $\theta$. They are (+,+) in the quadrant I (the comfortable quadrant...), (-,+) in quadrant II, (-,-) in quadrant III and (+,-) in quadrant IV.

Answer (score 0):

With trig convention for counterclockwise angles reckoned positive from x-axis:
$$ h= r ( \sin \alpha -\sin \beta);\quad w=r ( \cos \alpha -\cos \beta)\text{ for } \alpha> \beta. $$